# pandas how to get the date of n-day before monthend

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe, which the first column is the stock trading date. I represent the date with number for convenience here.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3],
                     'value': range(1, 11)})
```

I have another dataframe which contain the date of monthend. So that firstly I can get the row of monthend from data like this.

```
   date value
2  3.0  3.0
6  4.0  7.0
9  3.0  10.0
```

I want to get the data of n-days before monthend, for example, 1-day before

```
   date value
1  2.0  2.0
5  3.0  6.0
8  2.0  9.0
```

How can I code this.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the `cumsum` with `groupby`

```
df1=data.groupby(data.date.eq(1).cumsum()).tail(1)
df1
Out[208]: 
   date  value
2     3      3
6     4      7
9     3     10

df2=data.loc[df1.index-1]
df2
Out[213]: 
   date  value
1     2      2
5     3      6
8     2      9
```